# Displacement with C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am looking to implement a stack in a C program with which I was thinking about using an unsigned char * as a base. This would be the bottom of the stack and all other registers and information would be a displacement of this address. However, I cannot seem to understand how to do this properly. I was thinking of doing something like this...

```
//Info: Store 20 at address x0000007c

unsigned char * base = 0;
int address = x0000007c;
(base + address) = 20;
```

The C compiler does not like this so I was wondering how to fix this or do something similar without losing my pointer.

Comment: Not sure I get the question. you can't just set a pointer to some value you like and then away you go. A pointer has to point at something valid.

Comment: Strange. You used a pointer variable to store an integer value, and an integer to store an "address" (which isn't actually an address). Why? Which book are you reading?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour It's a Y86 emulator program from a C textbook in school. This assignment is designed to teach the fetch and execute cycle.

Comment: @MikeMelchione It seems like a very poor textbook.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour It's called Computer Systems, A Programmer's Perspective. Pretty good book in my opinion.

Comment: @MikeMelchione Why wouldn't you want to learn Russian and Hebrew simultaneously? For the same reason it doesn't make sense to learn x86 and C simultaneously. If the book is about C, then it shouldn't need to have references to x86 in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like your code because it's conceptually wrong; base + address is not an lvalue, and even if it were it has the wrong type: you can't store an int into a char*. But this is logically correct:

```
 base[address] = 20;
```

or, equivalently,

```
 *(base + address) = 20;
```

although it isn't functionally correct because base doesn't point to valid memory. You need to allocate your stack, either as a static array or via malloc, and assign it to base, e.g.,

```
 unsigned char* base = malloc(STACKSIZE);
 if (!base) out_of_memory();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I never allocated the memory with malloc so I was getting Segmentation Faults.

Comment: @melchyy If my answer helped you then you can upvote it, and accept it in a few minutes.

Comment: @Balter I actually don't have enough rep to upvote but I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

For a stack, the easiest is probably to use two pointers,

```
enum { STACKSZ = 100 };
char *base = malloc(STACKSZ);
char *top = base;
```

Then you can push with

```
*top++ = 'H';
```

and pop with

```
char x = *--top;
```

and get size with

```
int sz = top-base;
```

Note this code doesn't check for stack over-/under-flow.